# what to use instead of laptop-mode?

Tags: ubuntu, cooling

I have Ubuntu 10.10 64-bit on HP 6735s (turion processor). it overheats, and i'm forced to use turion power control in order to keep core temperature to a reasonable level. 
one more measure that i use is putting my processors to conservative mode. that way, i'm perfectly happy with its performance, and heat is where it should be.

however, after my latest upgrade, something happened - cores are back to on demand by default, and I'm not sure if turion power control is working any more (*ps axu | grep urion* shows no process). in addition, i read somewhere that laptop-mode uses hdd spindown for preserving data/energy, and that hdds have only a limited amount of those spindowns, so laptop-mode usage can actually shorten the life of my hdd.

I'm wondering if there is a good way to set my cores to automatically go to conservative mode? also, what's the good way to see what is the voltage my cores use? on windows i use cpuz tools.

Comment: You can configure laptop-mode to spin down the disk less often or not at all (though [it's not clear how harmful spindowns actually are](http://superuser.com/questions/197862/how-harmful-is-a-hard-disk-spin-cycle) — there's a theory that they *reveal* problems rather than cause them).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use the [`cpufrequtils`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/maverick/cpufrequtils) package to do similar things.  I generally tend to leave the governor set to ondemand and limit the upper bound of processor speed.  You can, however, also change the governor using these tools.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I used to use when I had AMD based laptop.
I used install following it used to save power and used to bring the cpu cycles down when not in use.

```
apt-get install powersaved
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thx for your reply. I'll check it out.