# Does shutting down regularly harm laptop or Windows?

Tags: windows, sleep, shutdown

I  usually work with my laptop and always shut it down for studying or doing other works (for half hour to two hours, about 6 times/day).

Is this harmful?

Comment: Why is this closed as not constructive? Seems like a valid question with a valid concern.

Comment: @Pacerier - "What is my best choice" is a question seeking an opionion.

Comment: @Ramhound, Just a matter of phrasing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally there is no exact answer however its best to not turn the laptop off and back
on a lot if it can be avoided. Shutting down the computer also uses power so for short
periods (many hours) using Sleep or better Hibernate would save power. Also allowing
electronices to cool and heat frequently is not the best for their long term use and
lifespan.

Using the Power Plans properly along with good Sleep and Hibernation settings, which
are dependent on how you use the computer, will get the best performance and lifespan
however there are no exact answers. Those which seem to be best for how you use the
system will probably also be best in the long run. If you "could" set with the magic settings
that would optimize the machines functions and life but then use the machine in a different
pattern, which we all would, then in fact you would actually get less use and lifespan than
setting to your use patterns.

One thing that many forget is that turning the screen off can also save power when you
will be away a short while and would not want to turn the computer off. This will save
some power over using a screensaver but can be hard to remember and does not save 
a lot.

Best to refer to your System maker's Support, their on-line documentation, and their
forums about your model.

Comment: Good answer. Was thinking the same thing about expansion and contraction from heating and cooling several times a day.

Comment: My concern is that "sleeping" a laptop actually shuts the (non SSD) hard-drive down, so using standby (a lot) adds wear and tear to the drive (and is, at least [partly, recorded](http://superuser.com/questions/312603/does-power-management-affect-a-hard-drives-smart-statistics) in the drive's SMART data).

Comment: @ahmed, Isn't hibernation effectively shutting down too? So if shutting down has a frequent cool-heat problem, why would it be different with hibernation?

Answer (score 2):

Shutting down your computer is not harmful. The reason people use sleep is because it's faster than having to wait for the computer to boot, and it keeps everything as you left it. But even then, you have to reboot or shutdown your computer *sometimes*. So the only thing wrong with always shutting down your computer is the time you'll lose waiting for it to boot.

Answer (score 1):

Shutting down a few times a day won't hurt anything.  I always recommend sleeping it during the day, and shutting down overnight.  This way it'll power back up quickly for you during the day, and get a fresh boot every morning so it stays running smoothly.