# Spinning disks + Hibernate/Suspend

Tags: hard-drive, debian, sleep, nas, suspend

Is it possible to put a linux system into suspend or hibernate mode and let the HDDs spinning? I have a proxmox setup as a NAS and i would like to save power during the night but I don't want to harm the HDDs with daily spin down and spin up.

Comment: Just leave the machine running and allow the monitor to turn black (suspend) but otherwise leave the machine on. That works for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I don't want to harm the HDDs with daily spin down and spin up.

This shouldn't harm the HDDs, as exactly the same thing happens whenever a regular desktop PC with an HDD is powered on in the morning and shut down in the evening. (Even more so with laptops, which can be suspended/resumed many times through the day.)

In fact, often computers do the opposite and automatically spin-down idle HDDs (in order to reduce power usage) even while the rest of the system is still powered on.

Of course, everything contributes to the wear, but you'll run out of disk space and upgrade the disks long before they have any chance to be noticeably damaged by nightly spin-down.

See also:

- [**How** harmful is a hard disk spin cycle?](https://superuser.com/questions/197862/how-harmful-is-a-hard-disk-spin-cycle)